# Wacom remote not working properly

Tags: hardware

I'd like to be able to use my wacom remote w/ blender but when I have Windows Ink enabled it lags in the viewport and when I have it off the radial menu function for the remote wont work.

I'd like to abandon using keyboard all together if I can by using the radial function as the majority of my hotkeys that I can't assign to the remote.

I've read/tried everything I can find on the remote/windows ink and have yet to find a solution.

I'm actually using an xp-pen cintiq if that matters. To my understanding the functionality of the remote wasn't reliant on having a wacom cintiq.